# Grails bind data to non-domain-class with type checking

Tags: grails, data-binding, grails-3.0

I'm looking for a simple way to check some types in my params. If they exist they should have a certain type, if  not they should have a default value. If they exist and their type is wrong, an exception should be thrown.

It would be nice to have the values in a handy container afterwards. Therefore I've tried passing `params` to the container's constructor and `bindData` on a container object. Neither is successful:

```
class ContainerClass {
     Integer foo = 42;
}

class TestController {

    def index(){
         //doesn't throw, **even when params.foo = "2asdf3"**
         ContainerClass meh = new ContainerClass();
         bindData(meh, params);

         println meh.foo //prints 42 when params.foo = "2asdf3"

         // throws GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '23' with class
         // 'java.lang.String' to to class 'java.lang.Integer',
         // **even when params.foo = "23"**
         ContainerClass meh2 = new ContainerClass(params);
         render "meh"
    }
}
```

I'm using grails 3 if this is of importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use Command Objects to bind parameters to certain Data Type.
Reference : http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html?utm_content=bufferf77f5&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer#commandObjects

If you want to throw exceptions if certain data type does not match,that needs to be checked explicitly.

Comment: Exceptions can be thrown too - from simple constraint validator to specific `grails.databinding.converters.ValueConverter`. See databinding part of documentation for details how to do that.

Comment: Well I can't unaccept this answer now, and it's nearly what I need, so that's ok. But there are some caveats: 
1) Default values are not possible. If a property is missing, `hasErrors` will return true, even if it has a default value set
2) When sending data via JSON it seems only the first of multiple CommandObject s is initialized. The second one presumably sees only an empty JSONObject and fails.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on 2nd point? Give an example?
For point 1, you can override the getter and modify accordingly.

Comment: For 2): Lets say I have two Command Objects `Foo` and `Bar`. In an action I can pass them both: `myAction(Foo foo, Bar bar){...}` (at least the docu says so). When passing JSON to the action `foo` will be initialised, `bar` not.